# ios get facebook access token and send it to server

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm creating an app with client-server model and trying to integrate facebook authorization, as I understand I need to use IOS SDK and create a stand alone app, than log in facebook using loginView in my app, get access token and send it to the server. So my problem is I can't find any example with this solution and can't find how to get token. I've tried to use

```
- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session state:(FBSessionState) state error:    (NSError *)error
{
switch (state)
{          
    case FBSessionStateOpen:
    {
        //https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=%@accessToken = [[FBSession activeSession] accessToken];
        NSLog(@"accessToken: %@",accessToken); 
...
```

but as I see it never calls, I didn't get access token after authorization. Could someone help me with a solution?

Comment: It's not that hard to do, did you follow the tutorials in the documentation?  If you don't follow those steps then the session will never open.

Comment: I've successfully logged in and logged out, but access token haven't shown.